# WPF DataGrid with only one combobox in templatecolumn not adding new rows

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm completely new to WPF so please apologise any "stupid" mistakes.
I have a datagrid with only one column, that is a combobox. The datagrid shows a new empty line as expected. But if I select a value in the combobox on the new line, no additional new row is added. I already tried to add an edit template according to this answer: [datagrid showing one new row, but not any subsequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717291/datagrid-showing-one-new-row-but-not-any-subsequent?rq=1) but that did no help.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFSpielplatz.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:WPFSpielplatz"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <d:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroceryItems}" CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combo">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.GroceryItemTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding GroceryItemType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" ></ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.GroceryItemTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding GroceryItemType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" ></ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using WPFSpielplatz.Annotations;

namespace WPFSpielplatz
{
public class MainWindowViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private ObservableCollection<GroceryItem> _groceryItems;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

        GroceryItemTypes = new ObservableCollection<GroceryItemType>
            {
                new GroceryItemType("Food"),
                new GroceryItemType("Non-Food")
            };

        _groceryItems=new ObservableCollection<GroceryItem>
            {
                new GroceryItem(){GroceryItemType=GroceryItemTypes[0]},
                new GroceryItem(){GroceryItemType=GroceryItemTypes[1]}
            };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GroceryItem> GroceryItems
    {
        get { return _groceryItems; }
        set
        {
            _groceryItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroceryItems");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GroceryItemType> GroceryItemTypes { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
}
```

The "domain" classes:

GroceryItem:

```
namespace WPFSpielplatz
{
public class GroceryItem
{
    public GroceryItemType GroceryItemType { get; set; }

    public GroceryItem()
    {
    }
}
}
```

GroceryItemType:

```
namespace WPFSpielplatz
{
public class GroceryItemType
{
    public GroceryItemType()
    {

    }

    public GroceryItemType(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroceryItems}"/>
```

is simply enough for binding your collection to the DataGrid. It is already relative, however you just need to bind your properties of the `GroceryItem` class to your DataGrid as follows:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroceryItemType.Name, Mode=TwoWay"}/>
```

This will insert the name for every `GroceryItemType` to the associated `GroceryItem` in a ComboBox. You will probably end up in having just the name of the `GroceryItemType` in the ComboBox since you did specify this as your `ItemsSource`. I don't think that is what you want but for now, I don't see any more code in order to understand, what you want to archive.

Please note that you will **have to** implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in both Models (`GroceryItem` and `GroceryItemType`) if you want to reflect the changes to the ViewModel and vice versa. This is where the `Mode=TwoWay` comes in handy.

Comment: I just wanted to inform you that your suggested way of databinding does not work. If I databind in the way you suggested not even the types of the existing items (that are constructed in the ctor of the MainWindowViewModel) are shown and all comboboxes do not hold any value. Also my example has so little code because I wanted to build a minimal example that could reproduce the problem.

Comment: Then it seems you have done something wrong. However, I can't help you if you don't provide any further code to prove this. As far as I can see from your answer, you are already using my suggestions and it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. It worked all the time, the problem was, that my `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>` and my `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>` looked the same so I could change values in the combobox without ever entering editing mode. But only after entering and successfully leaving editing mode a new row is added to the datagrid.

To get this working you have to click **multiple** times in the cell you want to edit and then **tab out of it** for the new row to be added.

So the updated code for the View looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFSpielplatz.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:WPFSpielplatz"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <d:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding GroceryItems}" CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combo">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroceryItemType.Name}" ></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>Edit</TextBlock>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.GroceryItemTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding GroceryItemType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name" ></ComboBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```